# Issue with php syntax on href link

Tags: php

I have this code which i want to use in order to access a page, with the id of the product.

The issue is, i don't get the id on the link.. what am i doing wrong here?

```
   echo'<a href="pershkrim.php?id="'.$row["id"].'"">"'.$row["id"].'"</a>';
```

Thanks.

Comment: replace with `echo'<a href="pershkrim.php?id='.$row["id"].'">'.$row["id"].'</a>';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead :

```
echo'<a href="pershkrim.php?id='.$row["id"].'">"'.$row["id"].'"</a>';
```

The problem was that with your echo your link looked like this:

```
<a href="pershkrim.php?id="777">"777"</a>';
```

Comment: @koopajah - still too many quotes.. `echo'<a href="pershkrim.php?id='.$row["id"].'">'.$row["id"].'</a>';` is enough !! :)

Comment: The quotes for the link text are not a problem so why remove them? I don't know what he is doing with the link or what he wants to display, I just corrected the bug

Comment: @koopajah - agree with you, he might wants to display the quotes !! :)

Comment: @koopajah - +1 from my side ;)

Answer (score 1):

You have too many quotes and they close before the id in the link

```
echo'<a href="pershkrim.php?id='.$row["id"].'">'.$row["id"].'</a>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Change to

```
echo'<a href="pershkrim.php?id='.$row["id"].'">'.$row["id"].'</a>';
```